# objects unable to change its own member's values

Tags: javascript, object

I have created object type a which has member x and y, also some functions changing the members' value.
I have seen the members been changed in debugger. But none of the members are changed. Can you explain?
Is there any difference in behaviour of x and y? one is local variable and the other is a parameter.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="debug"></div>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function a(y) {
            var x = 0;
            return {
                x: x,
                y: y,
                getX: getX,
                getY: getY,
                processX: processX,
                processY: processY,
            }
            function getX() {
                return x;
            }
            function getY() {
                return y;
            }
            function processX() {
                this.x = 1;
            }
            function processY() {
                this.y = 100;
            }
        }
        $(function () {
            var objs = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                objs[i] = a(i);
            }
            objs[0].processX();
            objs[1].processY();
            objs.forEach(function (o) {
                $("#debug").append($("<p>").text(o.x + " " + o.y));
                $("#debug").append($("<p>").text(o.getX() + " " + o.getY()));
//result:
//1 0
//0 0
//0 100
//0 1
//0 2
//0 2
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Strangely if i write a function to access the members, the correct values can be obtained.
why???

Comment: There's no difference between local variables (`var` keyword) and fucntion parameters, but there is one to object properties (members).

Answer (score 4):

You have to explicitly involve `this` when you want to modify object properties:

```
        function getX() {
            return this.x;
        }
        function getY() {
            return this.y;
        }
        function processX() {
            this.x = 1;
        }
        function processY() {
            this.y = 100;
        }
```

In your original code, references to "x" and "y" inside those four functions would be resolved to the local variables "x" and "y" inside the outer function (the function called "a").  That "a" function includes a parameter called "y" and a `var` declaration for "x".

Comment: so, if i do not, it will make a new local variable?
how come i can access the values?

Comment: @user1978421 in this particular case, "x" in the "processX" function would refer to the "x" declared in function "a", and the "y" in "processY" would refer to the "y" parameter to function "a".

Comment: which x and y does it refer for the x and y inside the return block??

Comment: Same ones. If there's no local `var` declaration, then JavaScript looks step by step through the layers of enclosing functions.  If there's no explicit declaration, then "x" and "y" would be treated as global variables (except in "strict" mode now, in which case such references would be erroneous).

Comment: oh i see.
so it's really referencing itself!

Comment: But how come this.x and this.y suggested by pointy would work?

Comment: In JavaScript, it's **always** necessary to explicitly include `this.` when referencing object properties. Unlike languages like Java, `this` is never implicit in JavaScript.

Comment: sorry, didn't realize you are the same person.
like what you said, x: x is referencing itself. Then, it should go back to the global scope to look for a value, the erroneous one, no matter using this or not. Do you understand what i am saying?